# How would you parse `du -s` using PHP?

Tags: php, bash, explode

How would you parse the output from the linux command `du -s` using PHP so that you can get the disk usage in kilobytes?

Example Output From `du -s`:

```
du: cannot access `./proc/11918/task/11918/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/11918/task/11918/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/11918/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/11918/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
223816 .
```

Desired PHP result:

```
223816
```

I've thought about using explode and count to get the last row then stripping off everything but numbers... but I'm sure there's a more efficient method out there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `du cannot access...` are error codes, you can do `du -s 2>/dev/null` to get rid of them.

Comment: I definitely like the answer... Then all I'd have to do is preg_replace everything but numbers. It'd work for sure... my question is will that filter out everything but the desired result?

Comment: (lunch time :D) @JustinJohnston now you would get just the last line: `223816 .` In general, yes, it should just leave the desired result. All the error codes will disappear with `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [disk_free_space()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) function, it does exactly that and is native to PHP. You can combine it with [disk_total_space()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php) to get utilization.

Comment: My script is actually connecting to remote servers via SSH so that unfortunately is not an option.

Comment: Another alternative might be parsing the output of `df` -- it still is ages faster than `du`, and has 1K blocks as a result.